# Script to delete all files and keep only latest file

Tags: linux, shell-script

Any advise on how to do delete all files and only keep the latest file in each sub-directories, starting from a specific directory?
This is what I have tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/ftp/ -type f | while IFS= read -r line
do
  find "$line" -type f | head -n -1 | while read file
  do
    #rm -f "$file"
    echo "$file"
  done
done
```

I have 2 sub-directories in /home/ftp/upload and /home/ftp/download. Both sub-directories have 2 files in each of the sub-directories.

When tested the script above, there is no file name echo out.

Comment: try something yourself first... if you are new to command line and shell scripting, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/bash/topics and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide .. or search online, lots of them are there

Comment: HINT: `find $1 -type f -exec stat --format '%Y :%y %n' "{}" \; | sort -nr | cut -d: -f2- | head -n1` will list the latest file name. Use this logic to develop your script. If you fails at some point, do ask.

Comment: Edit that exact command into your question and specify what result you are getting and what result you expect.

Comment: Your first `find` should be `-type d` to select the directories.  Note, though, that the second `find` doesn't _order_ the results so you may end up keeping files at random, rather than "latest".

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, from the current directory:

```
for dir (**/*(N/)) {
  files=($dir/*(N.om))
  (($#files > 1)) && echo rm -f -- $files[2,-1]
}
```

If you want hidden directories and files considered, add the `D` glob qualifier.

That only considers *regular* files. If you want other types of files like devices, sockets, named pipes, or if you want to follow symlinks, it can be adapted with more glob qualifiers.

Remove the `echo` to actually do the task.

With recent GNU tools and a POSIX shell:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
find . -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
  sort -rzn |
  cut -zf2- |
  gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' '
    match($0,/.*\//) && n[substr($0,1,RLENGTH-1)]++' |
  xargs -r0 echo rm -f
)
```